# Class variables reset after every phpunit test

Tags: php, phpunit

In my PHPUnit tests, I have a test and a data provider which provide some integer values to test. And I'm doing some logical tests with them. After that I want to store all these integer values in a class-scope variable.

```
private $numbers = [];

/**
 * @dataProvider dp
 */
public function testOne($data)
{
    foreach($data as $n)
        array_push($this->numbers, $n);

    var_dump($this->numbers);
}
public function dp()
{
    return [
        "first" => [[1,2]],
        "second" => [[3,4]],
    ];
}
```

Output:

```
.array(2) {
  [0] =>
  int(1)
  [1] =>
  int(2)
}
.                                                                  2 / 2 (100%)array(2) {
  [0] =>
  int(3)
  [1] =>
  int(4)
}


Time: 9.71 seconds, Memory: 34.00Mb
```

As you see, it's appending first data set's values (1,2) to `$numbers` and when 2nd data set started to test, something resetting the array and `$number` becoming (3,4) . However I was expecting it will be (1,2,3,4).

Can you tell me why `$numbers` array is empty before `second` data set?

I don't have a tearDown() method.

```
php -v
PHP 5.6.14-1+deb.sury.org~precise+1 (cli) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2015 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2015 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.6-dev, Copyright (c) 1999-2015, by Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.3.2, Copyright (c) 2002-2015, by Derick Rethans

phpunit --version
PHPUnit 5.0.4 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.
```

Comment: @Spudley :)) He / She removed down vote a few minutes later my comment, and then I removed my comment . Thank you.

Comment: Dunno if it's relevant but `'firsrt'` and `'second'` are keys pointing at an array within an array (trying ro say there's 2 sets of brackets) are you just passing `dp()['first']` to testOne?

Comment: @Terminus I have to set `array of array` to get `$data` as an array.  This is how data providers works. If i use one dimensional array, it will send `1` as first argument and `2` as second argument to testOne().

Comment: Gotcha. So when you var_dump($data) in testOne you would only see 1 and than 2 and than 3 and than 4.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to declare your property as static:

```
private static $numbers = [];

/**
 * @dataProvider dp
 */
public function testOne($data)
{
    foreach($data as $n)
        array_push(self::$numbers, $n);

    var_dump(self::$numbers);
}

public function dp()
{
    return [
        "first" => [[1,2]],
        "second" => [[3,4]],
    ];
}
```